# Force Firefox to allow auto signed certificate for localhost

Tags: localhost, ssl-certificate

To use Gmail SMTP on a local project, I had to change the virtualhost domain name from `https://4-9-6-fr.wp-dev/` to `https://wp-4-9-6-fr.dev/` because Google API does not want `wp-dev`. I imagine `wp-dev` was considered as a domain and `4-9-6-fr` as a subdomain.

My new problem is `.dev` is a good extension for Gmail but Firefox got this error :

> wp-4-9-6-fr.dev uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not safe because it is self-signed. The certificate is valid only for. Error Code : MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT

I understand it is a security action but in my case it is a localhost project.

What should I do to use https protocol on localhost / be compatible for Google API and gmail SMTP and be compatible for browsers as well ?

Comment: you need to create a new self signed certificate with new domain name in SAN. and better to use .test instead of .dev